# Reading EditTextPreference

Tags: java, android, edittextpreference

I can't seem to understand why I keep getting the "default" string show up when I grab input from the EditTextPreference.

```
<EditTextPreference
       android:title="@string/settings_title_signature"
       android:summary="@string/settings_enter_signature"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:key="edit_signature_key"
/>
```

I never seem to get what the textfield has using Sharedpreferences. It just defaults to the "default", and not what should be in the key.

```
SharedPreferences myPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String sig = myPreference.getString("edit_signature_key", "default");
```

Comment: go thought this even its bit old-> https://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/tag/edittext-preference-summary/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the EditTextPreference inside of a Preference Screen or Preference Fragment.  Sounds like you are just using a standalone EditTextPreference.

If you are using it in the right container, please update your post with all of your code and I will be able to help.

(had to put this as an answer instead of a comment because I don't have enough rep)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions mate. Though I'm modifying part of a large repository on git-hub, so putting the whole code here may be a little too much.

I did re-write shared preferences to this:
     SharedPreferences myPreference = this.getSharedPreferences("edit_signature_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

But still stuck with the same problem.

Comment: No problem my dude.  If you are using a PreferenceScreen or PreferenceFragment then it will write to you default preferences, so that is not where the problem is.  Only thing I can think of is if your update methods are not setup correctly, like in your onCreatePreferences method where the preferences are set up, you should have onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPrefs, getString(R.string.editKey)); and then in your Strings have  <string name="editKey">edit_signature_key</string>